# Can't deploy react project on vercel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vercel

```bash
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-scripts@5.0.0
npm ERR! Found: typescript@5.1.6
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   typescript@"^5.1.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">= 2.7" from fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@"^6.5.0" from react-dev-utils@12.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-dev-utils
npm ERR!       react-dev-utils@"^12.0.0" from react-scripts@5.0.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!         react-scripts@"5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (tsutils)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@4.9.5
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1 || ^4" from react-scripts@5.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-07-21T06_32_03_053Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-07-21T06_32_03_053Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

I deleted the `node-modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: For future questions, please add formatting for the error message to make it easier for others to provide answers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this error is related to a dependency conflict. You are trying to install react-scripts@5.0.0, which requires a peer dependency of typescript@">= 2.7", but there is a conflicting peerOptional dependency with typescript@4.9.5.

Comment: I tried this and it works  npm install typescript@4 --force